# How to visualize the vertices of a graph in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, osm2po

I tried to visualize the graph generated by osm2po and rendered that graph in qgis. Now what I am trying to do is plot the vertices in the graph. So that I can visually see where the nodes/vertices are. I have attached a screenshot of the visualization I have up to now.

[image]

I want to actually see the nodes in this

I followed the suggestion as given by underdark. However, I could see that the number of nodes and edges is less than that in the database. In the database the number of nodes = 32 and the number of edges = 39. However in my case it is 31 nodes only and 38 edges only. What could be the reason?

[image]

Comment: do you want also the line start/end points?

Answer (score 2):

I guess you mean something like this:

[image]

Create a symbol with one line layer and two marker layers. Put the markers on the first and on the last vertex:

[image]

Comment: Hi underdark, I followed the same method you mentioned and I could see the nodes. However, the number of nodes is less that that available in the database. I have total of 32, but in the plot which I am attaching to the original question it is less than that. Also the number of edges are lower in number. What could be the reason?

Comment: maybe duplicates with exactly the same geometry? it's hard to guess without being able to inspect the data.

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to enable the this line (by removing the leading #) in the config.

## postp.2.class = de.cm.osm2po.plugins.PgVertexWriter

It's another osm2po-table which contains the vertices.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the menu Vector -> Analysis tools -> Line intersections and you can create a point layer with some of the nodes.