# How to draw nodes of a graph in Python and link them to a table?

Tags: qgis-plugins, python-2.7

I would like to draw some points with a Python GUI, like a graph, and link those points to a table.

Comment: Could you please explain what this question has to do with GIS?  Also, details will be needed for anybody to give you a good answer.

Comment: i see some tutoriel,it's show that QGIS can draw graphs with python but it doesn't show how or the setup to make it

Comment: It sounds potentially interesting. But still, we need more details, please.

Comment: Are you trying to do something with graph theory?  http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27496/how-to-visualize-the-vertices-of-a-graph-in-qgis

Comment: yes,this is my graduation subject to draw graphes and to calculate the shortest path between nodes in python but the python tkinter is hard, not like the others language, if there is any idea please help me,i'm lost